# Gridview , how to simple higlight the results of a searched termn in the gridview?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

- I have a simple gridview in my page and a search function

  ( with SqlDatSource.SelectCommand="Select * From table where column name like etc..." ).

  - If I search something , it will return the results in the gridview.
  - How can I highlight the words searched in the gridview?

Thank you

Comment: Try these similar Questions&Answers:<br>
[Search keyword highlight in ASP.Net C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1629928/search-keyword-highlight-in-asp-net-c-sharp)<br>
[Highlight all matching strings/substrings on a datagrid from a keyword search](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6825700/highlight-all-matching-strings-substrings-on-a-datagrid-from-a-keyword-search)<br><br> Hope it'll help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey you can achive this through Grid Data Bound...

```
 public TextBox txtSearch = new TextBox();
 txtSearch.Text = "Goswami";

protected void grd_RowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{           
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        foreach(TableCell tc in e.Row.Cells)
        {
            tc.Text = tc.Text.Replace(txtSearch.Text, "<span style='color:Red;'>" + txtSearch.Text + "</span>");
        }
    }            
}
```

Comment: how can I add multiple columns?

Comment: yep the code works but I get string cannot be of zero length param name old value, I used tetsearch.text = textbox1.text

Comment: ok I fixed that , but now how can I get all rows that contains a part from the searched term?

Comment: Debugg your textbox if value is blank need to store in viewstate and retrive from there... or you can aslo add one codition if text != "" perform operiton

Comment: yep I Fixed, but how can I get in the gridview all rows that contains a part of the searched term?

Comment: Data Bound event Excuate Row by row so you dont have to worry about that... its apply on all row..

Comment: Hey Accept answer also if you satisfy... with soltuion.. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps and you should get the result wanted:

1. Bind the searchable fields (name, desc, etc...) dynamically using an
   Item Template column with a literal control inside it.
2. In your itemdataboind event do an if statement checking whether your
   data contain this word (car for example)and replace it with car